# Function that takes an STL iterator over ANY container of a elements of a specific type

Tags: c++

How would I define a function that takes as input an iterator over any type of STL container, but only to those of a specific templated type. For example:

Any iterator of the form `std::list<Unit*>::iterator` **or** `std::vector<Unit*>::iterator`

I would just define the function to take `std::list<Unit*>::iterator`, but if we switch to a different STL container, I don't want to have to change my code.

Is there a way to do this with templates or otherwise?

Comment: `std::list`? Raw pointers in STL containers? Gah! :)

Answer (score 16):

You could use a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) construct such as [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) which verifies if the nested typedef `iterator::value_type` is indeed of the appropriate type.

```
template<class T, class Iterator>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<typename Iterator::value_type, T> >::type
    f(Iterator i)
{
    /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> l;
    std::vector<int> v;

    f<int>(l.begin()); // OK
    f<int>(v.begin()); // OK

    std::vector<float> v2;
    f<int>(v2.begin()); /* Illegal */
}
```

This is what I understand from "a function that takes as input an iterator over any type of STL container, but only to those of a specific templated type", but my interpretation might be wrong.

Comment: What does this function return?

Comment: @OlegYablokov it's convention in template metaprogramming to create helpful aliases such as `typedef T type` nested inside the TMP structs. You would expect the return type in the example to be `T` or whatever would make sense in the context, maybe an iterator instead of a value, even though that's not explicitly mentioned nor used here.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the existing answers relying on SFINAE, a simpler approximation would be to simply define the function to take an arbitrary template type as the iterator:

```
template <typename Iter>
void function(Iter first, Iter last){
  Unit* val = *first;
}
```

This has a few downsides. Unlike the SFINAE solution (such as `boost::enable_if`), this doesn't give you *exactly* what you asked for. This compiles as long as an object of type `Iter` can be dereferenced yielding a value *convertible to `Unit*`*, which isn't quite the same thing. You have no guarantee that `Iter` is a completely STL-compliant iterator (it may just be another type which defines `operator*`), or that its value type is `Unit*` precisely.

On the other hand, it's much simpler.

Answer (score 6):

You only want to iterate over containers of `my_special_type`? In that case:

```
template <bool, typename T>
struct enable_if;

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    enum {value = false};
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

template <typename Iter>
typename enable_if<is_same<typename Iter::value_type, your_special_type>::value,
                  void>::type
function(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting! However, what happens here if the function is used with the incorrect type? Sorry if this is trivial. I'm still learning templates.

Comment: @Ryan: `enable_if` only has the `type` member if the first template parameter is `true`.  If you use the incorrect you will fail to compile.

Comment: @Ryan: The function does not *exist* for incorrect types thanks to `enable_if` :)

Comment: This will fail if `std::vector<your_special_type>::iterator` is `your_special_type*`, which the standard allows. Use `iterator_traits` for iterator-dependent types.

Answer (score 6):

Another way with templates is to trigger a static assertion if the condition is not met.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>    
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template <class Type, class Iter>
void foo(Iter from, Iter to)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type, Type>::value));
    //...
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    foo<int>(arr, arr + 10);    //OK
    foo<double>(arr, arr + 10); //triggers static assertion
}
```

If you want to do away with templates, then it is also possible to write an "any_iterator" using type erasure. For example, like this on: http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1any__iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Well i would use a simple typedef in the case that you only need one container-type at the time (if i understood your usecase correctly this is the case)

```
template <class T>
class ContainerIterator
{
  Container();
  public:
    typedef std::list<T>::iterator type;
}

//usage:
void function(ContainerIterator<YourType>::type begin, ContainerIterator<YourType>::type end)
{
  //...
}
```

to switch the container later on, simply change the container type in the typedef.