# Is it possible to have C++ template function which takes any collection of type T?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I was wondering if there is a way to create a template function which takes a reference to ANY collection of a specific type. i.e. something like:

```
class Bob
{
  public:
  int age;
  int height;
}

template<class T>
void functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(T &bobs)
{
    int totalAge = 0;
    for(auto &bob: bobs)
    {
         totalAge += bob.age;
    }
}
```

Basically is there a way to, in the definition of the template function, require that T have a begin() and end() function which return an iterator to T.

I've seen the following question, but that would require a function which takes a begin and end, i.e.

```
std::vector<Bob> bobs;
functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(bob.begin(), bob.end());
```

when what I would like is:

```
std::vector<Bob> bobs;
functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(bobs);
```

[Function that takes an STL iterator over ANY container of a elements of a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354665/function-that-takes-an-stl-iterator-over-any-container-of-a-elements-of-a-specif)

Comment: "require that T"...that T what?

Comment: Fixed the sentence above.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of providing overloads or giving better error messages?

Comment: If you try to use those functions and they don't exist for T, the code won't compile.  What's the problem?

Comment: What you are looking for are called ["concepts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29). For a variety of reasons they never made it into any C++ spec and possibly never will.

Comment: @EdS. I wanted a way to "decorate" the function, so it's clear to the users of the function what class T is required to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to keep the overload set unpolluted, use expression SFINAE like so:

```
template<class T>
void functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(T &bobs)
  -> decltype(std::begin(bobs), std::end(bobs), void()) {
    // [..Range based for over bobs..] 
}
```

Keep in mind though that the function template shown by you won't instantiate without an error if given a wrong argument, so this is currently superfluous - until you start overloading `functionWhichIteratesOverBobs`.

Comment: That's not quite the right way to check for usability in a range-for.

Comment: @T.C. Are you saying that one should check expressions like  `*std::begin(bobs)` as well?

Comment: Not really. I was referring to the case where the correct `begin()` and `end()`  are found by ADL.

Comment: @T.C. Ahhh, right. I forgot that range-based for's begin-expr is not quite equivalent to std::begin...

Comment: @T.C. Is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b162ee8986c05fe1) a correct implementation of ADL begin/end?

Comment: Well, that does take ADL into account, but I think it's still not quite right for range-for. In particular, if it has `.begin()/end()` members, and ADL also finds a free `begin()` that's indistinguishable from `std::begin()` during overload resolution, then your `adl_begin` will fail while the range-for will work.

Comment: @T.C. Right, what about http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f2e449e29405117 ? (Edit: Adjusted the test code)

Answer (score 0):

The C++ concept [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) has a member type `value_type` the type of the contained elements, so you can use SFINAE just as you would with an iterator - it's even simpler, because you don't need to use `iterator_traits`:

```
template<class T>
auto functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(T &bobs)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename T::value_type, Bob>>
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that this won't work with raw arrays; if you want those to work you would use `decltype(std::begin(bobs))` and `iterator_traits`:

```
template<class T>
auto functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(T &bobs) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<
    typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(bobs))>::value_type, Bob>>
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

As [Ed S. comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404651/is-it-possible-to-have-c-template-function-which-takes-any-collection-of-type#comment46985076_29404651), just use the same function which you wrote in your question. If the `bobs` doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` then compiler will notify you by generating error.
[Demo](http://ideone.com/YHCT0Z).

Answer (score 0):

With C++ 20 you can use the range concept:

```
#include <ranges>
template<std::ranges::range T>
void functionWhichIteratesOverBobs(T &bobs)
```

This will check that T is a range, i.e. has begin and end.

There are more fine grained concepts in the range library.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges#Range_concepts

I find this much more readable than SFINAE